# How can I include an svg graphic into a tufte-book document?

Tags: tufte, svg, inkscape

I've used Inkscape to create this figure (though perhaps not to a sane scale). I can edit this and export it to whatever file format might make things easiest. I'm also willing to use other tools to do further conversion if that is necessary.

The figure is a single color, and uses a handful of paths, but I don't think I could recreate it with the tikz stuff, at least not by hand. I'd like to do it as a margin figure (it looks sort of bad scaled up large), but margin figures seem to do `/input{file_no_extension]` and it doesn't seem to be compatible with export-latex option. There's also a save option with Latex+PSTricks which saves it as a .tex file, the results of which are smaller than I figured (and somewhat human-readable). My skill level's pretty low, and I'm mostly working off the tufte-book example, so I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: simplest is to save it as pdf from inkscape then just use `\includegraphics[width=10cm]{file.pdf}` in latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. 10cm is a little big, but thanks for thinking to include that too... I'd never have figured out the option myself. Now to dial it in...